# Mysterious iOS crash log, no exception

Tags: ios, swift, crash

I got a high amount of crash reports for an app via XCode Organizer / Crashes tab

However the stack trace does not show any exception type, just point to a recursive method run in a background thread (via dispatch_async) (and no it's not infinite recursion, it's a search method with limited depth). I have no clue to figure out why this crash occurs. I try to reproduce the crash in real devices but cannot. Could this be an intensive cpu task and gets killed by the OS? How do I verify if that is the case?  Any help would be appreciate!

```
#0  (null) in _TFC11MyAppFree17SearcherP33_D7BE9E167FAD2091BF2475359F0659466searchfS0_FTSi5aSi4bSi_Si ()
#1  (null) in _TFC11MyAppFree17SearcherP33_D7BE9E167FAD2091BF2475359F0659466searchfS0_FTSi5aSi4bSi_Si at Searcher.swift:115
#2  (null) in _TFC11MyAppFree17SearcherP33_D7BE9E167FAD2091BF2475359F0659466searchfS0_FTSi5aSi4bSi_Si at Searcher.swift:115
#3  (null) in _TFC11MyAppFree17SearcherP33_D7BE9E167FAD2091BF2475359F0659466searchfS0_FTSi5aSi4bSi_Si at Searcher.swift:115
#4  (null) in _TFC11MyAppFree17SearcherP33_D7BE9E167FAD2091BF2475359F0659466searchfS0_FTSi5aSi4bSi_Si at Searcher.swift:115
#5  (null) in _TFC11MyAppFree17SearcherP33_D7BE9E167FAD2091BF2475359F0659466searchfS0_FTSi5aSi4bSi_Si at Searcher.swift:115
#6  (null) in _TFC11MyAppFree17SearcherP33_D7BE9E167FAD2091BF2475359F0659466searchfS0_FTSi5aSi4bSi_Si at Searcher.swift:115
#7  (null) in _TFC11MyAppFree17SearcherP33_D7BE9E167FAD2091BF2475359F0659466searchfS0_FTSi5aSi4bSi_Si at Searcher.swift:115
#8  (null) in _TFC11MyAppFree17SearcherP33_D7BE9E167FAD2091BF2475359F0659466searchfS0_FTSi5aSi4bSi_Si at Searcher.swift:115
```